# An Apache Web Server Message

Tags: javascript, eclipse, apache, tomcat, d3.js

I am trying to set up d3 Javascript by following this link:

> https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki . I am currently using Eclipse Juno and Tomcat in Mac 10.5.8. basically I am trying to run a simple Force-Directed graph example that was taken from the following link: 
>   https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4062045

I have been recommended to insert the command below into the Terminal in order to get d3 run:

> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &

With the Web Browser (Firefox in my case), I can insert:

```
http://localhost:8888/
```

. When I do this, I get the following message in the browser:

> If you can see this, it means that the installation of the Apache web server software 
>       on this system was successful. You may now add content to this directory and replace   this page.
>       Seeing this instead of the website you expected?
>
> This page is here because the site administrator has changed the configuration of this
>       web server. Please contact the person responsible for maintaining this server with questions.
>       The Apache Software Foundation, which wrote the web server software this site
>       administrator is using, has nothing to do with maintaining this site and cannot help resolve configuration issues.
>       The Apache documentation has been included with this distribution.
>       You are free to use the image below on an Apache-powered web server. Thanks for using Apache!

What that message means and why am I getting this type of message? How can I get the d3 run so long as I am getting this message?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that Apache and python are competing for the same port and since you start python in the background mode, it is not reporting the errors correctly.

Try starting `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` without an argument. It should start on port `8000` and serve the files from the folder it is started from.

The next steps would be to move the html file and the json file in the same folder where you started the server from. Then point your browser to `http://localhost:8000/<name-of-your-html-file>.html`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just to let you know. I just installed MAMP server and on the web browser, I have added: http://localhost:8888/sample/ . I have created a folder inside htdocs folder which comes along with MAMP server when you download it.